# Link from single post page to index page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

In Wordpress, is there an official way to link from a single post view to that post type's index view? I'm working with custom post types. I've googled around for a wordpress function but there doesn't seem to be one for this and I'd like to avoid hardcoding a URL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" >  Home </a>
```

Comment: That displays the homepage which is not what I'm looking for. I was wondering if there's a wordpress function for outputting the permalink to a custom post type's index page within the context of custom post type single view.

Comment: what do you mean by custom post type index page ? put some code